# Can I use a union to express a struct and multiple packed members?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, unions

Say I have a struct, `ivec2`:

```c
typedef struct ivec2 {
    int x, y;
} ivec2;
```

I'd like to know if I can make a union similar to the following:

```c
union rectangle {
    ivec2 size; // 8 bytes; members: int x, y;
    int width, height; // 4 + 4 bytes
};
```

where `width` corresponds to `size.x`, and `height` corresponds to `size.y`.

I've seen that it's possible to do this:

```c
union rectangle {
    ivec2 size; // 8 bytes
    int arr[2]; // 4 + 4 bytes
};
```

but can I do it with separate members?

This image shows what I'm getting at:

[image: Diagram of union]

Comment: No you can't do it with individual members of the union, because each individual member of the union shares the space with every other member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is nest an anonymous struct within the union.

Instead of:

```
union rectangle {
    ivec2 size;
    int width, height;
};
```

do:

```
union rectangle {
    ivec2 size;
    struct {
        int width;
        int height;
    };
};
```

Comment: Ah, so by using an anonymous struct, `width` and `height` are accessible directly as members of `rectangle`, right?  That's exactly the answer I needed.  Thanks for the quick response!